# lesskey config does not get used by less pager when used with git on OSX

Tags: linux, git, macos, bsd, less-unix

This works fine in Linux so I'm wondering if this is a problem with the version of less that the Mac is running.

I have the same `~/.lesskey` file set up, `lesskey` runs successfully in both places, the resulting `~/.less` are identical:

```
ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-0F-D6-5D:~/util 1:13:37
% md5sum ~/.less                                       
0d9f50f079b66b8ef8518940b6674a7e  /home/ec2-user/.less
% less --v                            
less 436
Copyright (C) 1984-2009 Mark Nudelman
```

And

```
slu@Stevens-MacBook-Pro:~/util 21:14
% md5 ~/.less                                             
MD5 (/Users/slu/.less) = 0d9f50f079b66b8ef8518940b6674a7e
% less --v                           
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

the keybindings apply for `man` use on the Mac as well. It is only when I run git related commands that the less reverts to regular keybindings.

Comment: How can you install lesskey on OSX? I can't find the program on the internet and it doesn't ship with 10.12.

Comment: I believe the way it works is lesskey is a component of the gnu (binutils?) less package. OSX comes with a BSD flavored less. So you just homebrew your less, and possibly might need to do stuff like I wrote in the answer here, and you get lesskey at that point. Should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!

Git was running `/usr/bin/less`, but I had set up less from source (And I discovered this issue when it occurred to me that I could install less from homebrew and it made me think).

So, manpages and just running `less` would run `/usr/local/bin/less`, but git for whatever reason would grab the original old one, which is not compatible with the lesskey config. `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in my path.

My solution, then, was `sudo mv /usr/bin/less /usr/bin/less-old`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `$LESS` environment variable?

According to git-config's [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) <sup>(core.pager)</sup>, it will set `$LESS` to `FRSX` if unset.
Could this be effecting your set up?

Comment: it reports $LESS is `-R` (same on the Linux environment)